# Returning of right type in a nested arrow function depending on parameters

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, deno

I have an arrow function that return other nested arrow function depending on the parameters

```
type Exist_Options = "true" | "ignore"

const string_parser = (o:Exist_Options) =>{
  switch (o) {
    case "true":
      return (v?:string) => {
        if (!v) {
          return true;
        }
        return v;
      };
    case "ignore":
      return (v?:string)=> {
        if (!v) {
          return null;
        }
        return v;
     };
  }
};
```

the expected types of these functions are:

```
//In "true" 
type Key_Parser_ST = { (v: string | undefined): string | true};
//In "ignore"
type Key_Parser_SN = { (v: string | undefined): string | null};
```

When assign the function with one of the parameter I want to get the right type back

```
//current type
//const string_parse: ((v?: string | undefined) => string | true) | ((v?: string | undefined) => string | null)

const string_parse = string_parser("true")

//what I would like to get
//const string_parse: (v?: string | undefined) => string | true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#overloaded-functions) type, you can get even nicer (more correct) return type inferences:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-JDaJxNmczyAJJYjiCo2SGRyCjinrYtMKtL4tabCkvU3qsmTlo66n6ulN42M83caqW60CW1QIccR0kdudhP6d2e8k5g8QAPHvAd3oJ2cXidba+n2P3x-YxPJjapueYYZv+ODZruQg3gW36nuKtb1hWRpVj48Hlo2iTZkAA)

```ts
type Exist_Options = 'true' | 'ignore';

const string_parser = ((o: Exist_Options) => {
  switch (o) {
    case "true":
      return (v?: string) => {
        if (!v) {
          return true;
        }
        return v;
      };
    case "ignore":
      return (v?: string) => {
        if (!v) {
          return null;
        }
        return v;
     };
  }
}) as {
  (o: 'true'): {
    (): true;
    (v: ''): true;
    <V extends string>(v: V): V;
  };
  (o: 'ignore'): {
    (): null;
    (v: ''): null;
    <V extends string>(v: V): V;
  };
};

const fnTrue = string_parser('true'); /* {
  (): true;
  (v: ''): true;
  <V extends string>(v: V): V;
} */
const true1 = fnTrue(); // true
const true2 = fnTrue(''); // true
const true3 = fnTrue('hello'); // "hello"
const true4 = fnTrue('another string'); // "another string"

const fnIgnore = string_parser('ignore'); /* {
  (): null;
  (v: ''): null;
  <V extends string>(v: V): V;
} */
const ignore1 = fnIgnore(); // null
const ignore2 = fnIgnore(''); // null
const ignore3 = fnIgnore('hello'); // "hello"
const ignore4 = fnIgnore('another string'); // "another string"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const parserMap = {
  true: (v?: string) => {
    if (!v) {
      return true;
    }
    return v;
  },
  ignore: (v?: string) => {
    if (!v) {
      return null;
    }
    return v;
  },
};

function string_parser<T extends keyof typeof parserMap>(o: T) {
  return parserMap[o];
}
```

Comment: It works, I'm surprised that I have to restructure all the function in order to get it to work with typescript